# LINQ query to transform CSV data

Tags: linq, csv, linq-to-objects

I'm new to LINQ and hoping someone can help me out writing this query to transform some data.  I have a `Dictionary<DateTime, string>` containing data like this....

```
<01/07/12 00:00, "23,5,654,12,55,45,12,46,673,325,377,234,867,43,1,123,53,12,23,667,23,45,456,87">

<02/07/12 00:00, "22,63,567,13,64,6,4,64,7,2,5,234,667,787,326,234,64,24,5,76,23,556,77,34">

<03/07/12 00:00, "3,746,34,623,5,76,23,6,23,2,78,4,234,76,4,6,8,7,4,3,7645,23,34,6">
```

etc...

This dictionary has an Key which is a Date and a Value which is a CSV string containing 24 numbers (one for each hour of the day starting at 00:00). I would like to convert it into a Dictionary

```
<01/07/12 00:00, 23>

<01/07/12 01:00, 5>

<01/07/12 02:00, 654>
```

etc...

I've been trying for a while now a thought the answer lay in using SelectMany, but just can't get anything to work.  I know I could just do it using some loops, but would really like to see a LINQ implementation.

Many thanks if you can help me.
Colin.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>
{
    { new DateTime(2012, 7, 1), 
        "23,5,654,12,55,45,12,46,673,325,377,234,867,43,1,123,53,12,23,667,23,45,456,87" 
    },
    { new DateTime(2012, 7, 2), 
        "22,63,567,13,64,6,4,64,7,2,5,234,667,787,326,234,64,24,5,76,23,556,77,34" 
    }
};

dict.Select (d => d.Value.Split(new []{','})
    .Select ((v,i) => new {
        DateTime=d.Key.AddHours(i), Value=v}))
    .SelectMany (d => d)
    .ToDictionary (d => d.DateTime, d => int.Parse(d.Value));
```